# X axis on a two-screen zoo plot

Tags: r, plot, zoo

This time I am struggling to adjust the X axis in a two-screen zoo plot.
Here's an example, inspired from a previous post:

```
x.Date <- as.Date(paste(rep(2003:2004, each = 12), rep(1:12, 2), 1, sep = "-"))
x <- zoo(data.frame(rnorm(24), rnorm(24)), x.Date)
```

then when I plot without X axis and add an axis separately

```
plot(x, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = time(x), labels = FALSE)
```

nothing happens (also with more complex versions of the axis, for example with labels)...
What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Benoit

Comment: You will have to use a panel function to do that.  See examples at the end of `?plot.zoo` .   Note that zoo also supports lattice graphics (`?xyplot.zoo`) and ggplot2 (`?autoplot.zoo`).

Comment: Thanks, I got it solved with xyplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use `xyplot.zoo` the lattice version of `plot.zoo`. Very easy to customize your x-axis using `scales` parameter.

```
 library(lattice)
 xyplot(x, 
   scales=list(
     x=list(  at=time(x),
              format='%y-%m')
   ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This does not work "off-the-shelf". What packages do I need to install?

Comment: Great, thanks, it works. Can you just tell me how I change the titles that appear above each chart (rnorm.24 and rnorm.24.1 in your example)?